# Self-initialization of a static constexpr variable, is it well-formed?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++14, constexpr, c++17

Given the following declaration in the global namespace:

```
constexpr int x = x;
```

Is this well-formed?

The draft C++14 standard section `3.6.2` *[basic.start.init]* says:

> Variables with static storage duration (3.7.1) or thread storage duration (3.7.2) shall be zero-initialized (8.5)
>   before any other initialization takes place. [...]

What seems to make the example well defined is that `x` is initialized with its own value during constant initialization which will be `0` due to zero initialization.

Is this really the case? clang [accepts this code](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/nULidJf0jVzsoxgd) while [gcc produces a diagnostic](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/rORwnVAg8cDsuCyM):

```
error: the value of 'x' is not usable in a constant expression
constexpr int x = x;
                  ^
```

Comment: It's never undefined behavior.

Comment: @T.C. when I mentioned UB, I was thinking of [this case](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14935722/1708801) and the related [c++14 version here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23415661/1708801). I had originally referenced them in the question but felt like it made less clear.

Comment: Sure, but in this context, anything that would be UB is not a constant expression, making the initialization ill-formed instead.

Comment: @T.C. ok, you make a good point. I, knew I should have left that out.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour replying to myself for the fun of it

Answer (score 24):

This was clarified and made ill-formed by [defect report 2026: Zero-initialization and constexpr](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#2026) which asks:

> According to 3.6.2 [basic.start.init] paragraph 2,
>
> > Variables with static storage duration (3.7.1 [basic.stc.static]) or
> >     thread storage duration (3.7.2 [basic.stc.thread]) shall be
> >     zero-initialized (8.5 [dcl.init]) before any other initialization
> >     takes place.
>
> Does this apply to constant initialization as well? For example,
>   should the following be well-formed, relying on the presumed
>   zero-initialization preceding the constant initialization?
>
> ```
> constexpr int i = i;
> struct s {
>   constexpr s() : v(v) { }
>   int v;
> };
> constexpr s s1;
> ```

The note before the proposed resolution says:

> CWG agreed that constant initialization should be considered as happening instead of zero initialization in these cases, making the declarations ill-formed.

and the proposed resolution clarifies and amongst many changes, removes the following wording:

> Variables with static storage duration (3.7.1) or thread storage duration (3.7.2) shall be zero-initialized (8.5)
>   before any other initialization takes place. [...]

and adds the following wording:

> If constant initialization is not performed, a variable with static storage duration (3.7.1 [basic.stc.static]) or thread storage duration (3.7.2 [basic.stc.thread]) is zero-initialized (8.5 [dcl.init]).  [...]

It is a large change, it renames *[basic.start.init]* to *[basic.start.static]* and created a new section *[basic.start.dynamic]* and modifies *[stmt.dcl]*