# C++ self-referencing array?

Tags: c++

I accidentally created a bug in a program by self-referencing in an array. Here's a very simplified demo program similar in concept:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int kTest[] = {
    kTest[0]
};

int main() {
    cout << kTest[0] << endl;
}
```

I was surprised that I received neither a compiler error or even a warning on this code! In my case it ended up producing unpredictable output. Is it accessing garbage memory?

I was curious about under what circumstances this would have well-defined output (if ever!).

**Edit**: Does it make a difference if `kTest` is `static`? What about `const`? Both?

Comment: hmm.  global `int`s are zero initialized so I wonder if because of that it is legal.

Comment: Under the circumstances in which the language standard allowed this sort of syntax.

Comment: It's not very different from [`int x = x;`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14935722/does-initialization-entail-lvalue-to-rvalue-conversion-is-int-x-x-ub).

Comment: Why would it be an error? `kTest` has been declared by the point of use. Globals are _normally_ initialized to 0, but since you are _manually_ initializing it, it initializes with the zeroth element --- which is garbage since it's still in the process of initializing.

Comment: @PaulJ.Lucas: Unfortunately, the C++ standard has no notion of "garbage" :-S

Comment: Is this actually the real code that produces the alleged "garbage"? Since this initialization is dynamic (given that the initializer is not a constant expression), `kTest` is guaranteed to be zero-initialized in the static phase.

Comment: The real fun begins when you make `kTest` into a `constexpr`. Then the magic UB-detector that is `constexpr` kicks in.

Comment: I think that this is formally UB only if the index in `kTest[...]` is equal to or larger than the number of entries in `kTest` (for example, if you used `kTest[5]` up there, without adding at least 5 more entries).

Comment: @KerrekSB No, this isn't the exact same code. It actually accessed another array at an *index* specified by the self-reference. And it was declared `static const`. I didn't think that stuff was overly relevant but maybe it was.

Comment: @KerrekSB note [it is ill-formed](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34276373/1708801) not UB so slightly different.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: I see, yes, but where does the ill-formedness come from? The issue resolution doesn't spell that out, it just seems kind of implied.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: I thought the ill-formedness you mention would be a consequence of [expr.const]/(2.6), because it *would* be UB to read an uninitialized variable.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
int kTest[] = {
    kTest[0]
};
```

is similar to, if not exactly same as

```
int x = x;
```

It will be undefined behavior, if declared locally in a function.

It seems to be well defined when `kTest` is a global variable. See [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40138652/434551) for additional details.

Comment: This should be more than an opinion shouldn't it? Or is whether or it's UB not defined by the standard?

Comment: Could it be unspecified? I guess it is similar to this: `int x; x = x;`.

Comment: @Carcigenicate, I see in the C++11 standard where `int x = x;` is discussed but I can't find anything that talks about the OP's situation.

Comment: I am not so sure, if you look at [Self-initialization of a static constexpr variable, is it well-formed?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34276373/1708801) as far as I can tell this should zero initialized.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not so sure this is undefined. Quote from the current [draft](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start):

> [basic.start.static]/3
>
> If constant initialization is not performed, a variable with static
>   storage duration ([basic.stc.static]) or thread storage duration
>   ([basic.stc.thread]) is zero-initialized ([dcl.init]). Together,
>   zero-initialization and constant initialization are called static
>   initialization; all other initialization is dynamic initialization.
>   *Static initialization shall be performed before any dynamic initialization takes place*.

To me it looks like `kTest` is already zero-initialized when the dynamic initialization starts, so it may be defined to initialize to `0`.

Comment: Your interpretation makes sense.`g++` did not complain about `int x = x;` when defined globally but complained when defined in a function.

Comment: Why do you assume that the OP's global initialization is dynamic? If I have `static int a[] = { 1 };` that is initialized statically only. `a[0]` is not initialized to 0 (statically) and then initialized again to 1 (dynamically).

Comment: @PaulJ.Lucas: *Together, zero-initialization and constant initialization are called static initialization; all other initialization is dynamic initialization.*

Comment: @Paul J. Lucas: Becuase it is not zero-initialization and it does not satisfy requirements of constant-initialization. That immediately makes it dynamic. Your `static int a[] = { 1 };` example is completely different. However, conceptually it **is** actually processed in two stages: as zero-initialization followed by initialization with 1. Both stages are *static* initialization though. It is C++17 that decieded to get rid of the unnecessary zero-initializtion when constant-initialization is present.

Comment: See [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40138325/c-self-referencing-array#comment67664922_40138406) I believe your interpretation is correct.