# Is initialization of static member of a class guaranteed before initialization of a static object of that class?

Tags: c++, static

I encountered this C++ static initialization order related query at a code review recently.

1. I've a class with static member variable in a compilation unit
2. I've a static object of that class using a constructor in a different compilation unit

Here, I want to know if the static member variable is guaranteed to be initialized before the static object constructor is called?

*MyClass.h*:

```
typedef int (*MyFunc)(int);
class MyClass {
MyClass(MyFunc fptr) {
    mFunc = fptr;
}
static MyFunc mFunc;
}
```

*MyClass.cpp*:

```
MyFunc MyClass::mFunc = nullptr;
```

*MyDifferentClass.h*:

```
MyDifferentClass {
public:
    static int MyStaticFunc(int);
}
```

*MyDifferentClass.cpp*:

```
static MyClass myClassObj(MyDifferentClass::MyStaticFunc);
```

In the code, would `mFunc` be initialized to `nullptr` before `myClassObj` gets created? The reason for the query is that if the order is not guaranteed, then `mFunc` may get initialized again to `nullptr`.

Comment: There is no reason to tolerate the unknown, nor leave this up to the linker.  Simply ensure the sequence using explicit code early in main().

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> In the code, would `mFunc` be initialized to `nullptr` before `myClassObj` gets created? The reason for the query is that if the order is not guaranteed, then `mFunc` may get initialized again to `nullptr`.

The answer to the question is "Yes".

Setting aside the issue of initialization of thread specific objects, initialization of non-local variables is carried out in the following order.

1. All variables are zero-initialized (order not specified). This is called *zero initialization*.
2. All variables that can be initialized using constant values are initialized. This is called *constant initialization*.

Those ( 1 and 2 above) are called *static initialization*.

After that, dynamic initialization is performed.

In your case, `MyClass::mFunc` is initialized using *constant initialization* while `myClassObj` is initialized using *dynamic initialization*. Hence, the former is guaranteed to be initialized first.

More on this topic can be found at https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/basic.start.init.

Comment: You are quoting C++11 but a lot of [basis.start changed due to defect report 2026](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34276374/1708801) for various reasons. So be careful.